# MongoDB show first and last event for each user for each day

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Each time a user logs in or logs out, an event is saved in mongo. A user can login and/or logout multiple times a day.

For example,  Bob has login 2 times  and logout 1 time:

```
{
  username: ‘bob’,
  type: ‘login’,
  eventDate: ISODate(‘2018-09-21T12:39:50.676Z’)
}

{
  username: ‘bob’,
  type: ‘login’,
  eventDate: ISODate(‘2018-09-21T13:55:50.676Z’)
}

{
  username: ‘bob’,
  type: ‘logout,
  eventDate: ISODate(‘2018-09-21T22:10:50.676Z’)
}
```

And James has just 1 login event:

```
{
  username: ‘james’,
  type: ‘login,
  eventDate: ISODate(‘2018-09-21T10:10:50.676Z’)
}
```

I would like to execute a query that would retrieve the **first** login of the day and the **last** logout of the day for each user for each day (let’s say during the past week).

So the result would be like:

```
[{
  username: ‘bob’,
  firstLogin: ISODate(‘2018-09-21T12:39:50.676Z’),
  lastLogout: ISODate(‘2018-09-21T22:10:50.676Z’)
}

{
  username: ‘james’,
  firstLogin: ISODate(‘2018-09-22T10:19:50.676Z’),
  lastLogout: null,
}]
```

I believe I have to deal with ‘aggregation’ but not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve by single `group`.

> Also work when you have different days for the same user.
>
> return last and the first date by `type`.
>
> tested on MongoDB GUI.

```
db.getCollection("loginDetail").aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        username: "$username",
        year: { $year: "$eventDate" },
        month: { $month: "$eventDate" },
        day: { $dayOfMonth: "$eventDate" }
      },
      firstLogin: {
        $min: {
          $cond: [{ $and: [{ $eq: ["$type", "login"] }] }, "$eventDate", null]
        }
      },
      lastLogout: {
        $max: {
          $cond: [{ $and: [{ $eq: ["$type", "logout"] }] }, "$eventDate", null]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
      $project: {
          _id: 1,
          username : '$_id.username',
          firstLogin :1,
          lastLogout :1
          }
      }
]);
```

Comment: You should use `$max` to find the last logout value.

Comment: Ya, Thanks. Its by mistak.

Answer (score 2):

By using two levels of `$group`: *(MongoDB V3.2.18)*

I believe **userName** is unique.

1. `$sort` **eventDate** first.
2. `$group` by **userName** and **type**.
3. `$project` to differentiate **firstLogin** and **lastLogin**.
4. `$group` again by **userName** for final result.

---

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
  {$sort: {'eventDate' : 1}},
  {
    "$group" : {
        _id: {"username" : "$username", "type": "$type"},
        eventDate: {$push: "$eventDate"}
    }
  },
  {
    $project : {
      _id:1,
      eventDate:1,
      firstLogin: {
        $cond: [ { "$eq": ["$_id.type", "login" ]}, { $arrayElemAt: [ "$eventDate", 0 ] }, null]
      },
      lastLogout: {
        $cond: [ { "$eq": ["$_id.type", "logout" ]}, { $arrayElemAt: [ "$eventDate", -1 ] }, null]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group" : {
        _id: "$_id.username",
        firstLogin: {$first: "$firstLogin"},
        lastLogout: {$last: "$lastLogout"}
    }
  }
]);
```

**Output:**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "james",
    "firstLogin" : ISODate("2018-09-21T10:10:50.676Z"),
    "lastLogout" : null
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "bob",
    "firstLogin" : ISODate("2018-09-21T12:39:50.676Z"),
    "lastLogout" : ISODate("2018-09-21T22:10:50.676Z")
}
```